# Logic questions: reasoning pattern, Infer literals, unit resolution, and-elimination etc

Tags: logic

> Show which literals can be inferred from the following knowledge bases, using both reasoning patterns and truth tables. Show all steps in your reasoning and explain your answers.
>
> 1) P & Q
>   2) Q →R v S
>   3) P → ~R

This is from my reasoning pattern tutorial, my text book shows similar question except that there is a single literal with workings, so I can somehow read through but I'm not familiar with some terms. I don't understand how I can infer all literals with the above information. I also don't fully understand what is and-elimination, modus ponens and unit resolution.

Is there anyone who is kind enough to use the above question as an example so that I can have a clearer picture?

Comment: I would like to note that the problem is not to infer _all_ literals, but to show which literals can be inferred.